# Visual studio relative reference path

Tags: visual-studio

I usually format my project directory like J-P Boodhoo. a main dir containing solution file, then a lib folder for all third-party lib, a src dir, a tools lib for third-party that wont be deployed.... [For more info look here](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/DirectoryStructureForProjects.aspx)

I set in my project the reference path for all the needed folder, but if a developper checkout the trunk, he have to set all the reference path. Is there a way to simplify this ?

And am I using Visual Studio 2008.

Thank you.

Comment: Suggestions: some of us don't know what "J-P Boodhoo" means, perhaps you could add a link?  Also, you might specify VS version and language, esp in the question title.

Comment: thanks for the edits.  Which language are you using?  I believe the rules for project files are different for VC compared to the other VS languages.  I believe the non-C++ languages use MSBuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which Visual Studio language you use, but if it's C++, then then file paths are stored in the `.vcproj` project file which should also be under version control.  (NOTE: the `.sln` solution file does NOT store path settings) If you are careful to use relative, rather than absolute paths, it should be easily sharable among multiple developers.

In Visual C++ 2008, [project files are XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2.aspx) so you can edit them directly.  If you want to get really fancy, you can use [`.vsprops` property sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx) for additional control.

Answer (score 1):

I use a shared folder on the network for stuff like that. And give that folder full trust. on the PDC i just have a login script that maps approriately. Its might not be the best way, but its worked for me without any issues.

Another solution I have used in the past is a common folder on each machine where all dependancies go, and have it syncronize with some sort of tool. I use Backup Exec which comes with Desktop and Laptop option which has a syncing feature, but other things work as well.

Comment: Sounds too complicated for the goal, and would not work on remote team( I know I did not mention the requirement), still thanks for the suggestion.